# Simple window resize react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm attempting to capture the window height and pass it to child components in react.

I'm referring to this guide from the manual: https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/dom-event-listeners.html.

This is how my code is looking but I'm getting a 'setState is not a function' error.

```
import React from 'react';
import jsonp from 'jsonp';
import Gallery from './Gallery.jsx';

export const MF = 'http://auryn/modern-frontend/public_html';

export default class App extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            images: [ 'DSCF1176.jpg' ],
            height: window.innerHeight+'px'
        };
        var self = this;

        // get images
        var url = MF+'/api/posts';
        jsonp(url, {}, function (err, data) {
            const blogs = data.data.blogs.map(item => {    
                return {
                    'images': item.image
                }
            });
            var images = [];
            blogs.forEach(b => {
                b.images.forEach(i => {
                    images.push(i.filename);
                });
            });
            //console.log(JSON.stringify(images));
            //self.images = images;
            self.setState({ images });
        });
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        window.addEventListener('resize', this.handleResize);
    }

    handleResize(e) {
        this.setState({height: window.innerHeight+'px'});
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        window.removeEventListener('resize', this.handleResize);
    }

    render() {   
        return (
              <Gallery images={this.state.images} height={this.state.height} />
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your handleResize function's body will get the window context. You can bind it to your component class in constructor :

```
constructor(){
  ...
  this.handleResize = this.handleResize.bind(this);
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't access the Component's attributes or functions from a different Context (in this case the Callback).
You need to bind your Callback function if you need to use your component as the Context, the function should look like this:

```
jsonp(url, {}, function (err, data) {
     // your code
     this.setState({ images });
}.bind(this));
```

Same goes for your `handlesize` function.

Comment: Thanks Ahmed however that's not the setState call that's failing. It's the second one.

Comment: I guess you should also bind handlesize preferably in the constructor, give it a shot