# window.innerHeight with React and redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I asked a question recently ([Simple window resize react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39671054/simple-window-resize-react)) to get most of this solution working however now I am plugging in redux so that I can refactor out the web service call to an action creator and receive the data through a reducer.  (The call is made using jsonp-promise and I am using the appropriate redux middleware.)

However now I can't seem to use window.innerHeight as it always returns 200 :/

Is the problem due to having some of state managed by redux and some of it native to the component (i.e. 'height')?

Many thanks in advance!

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import GalleryItem from '../components/gallery_item';
import Nav from '../components/nav';
import { fetchImages } from '../actions/index';

export const MF = 'http://www.veilcraft.com';


class Gallery extends Component {


    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            images: [],
            height: window.innerHeight
        };

        this.handleResize = this.handleResize.bind(this);
        this.props.fetchImages();
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        window.addEventListener('resize', this.handleResize);
    }

    handleResize(e) {

        this.setState({
            height: window.innerHeight
        });
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        window.removeEventListener('resize', this.handleResize);
    }

    render() {

        console.log(this.props.height); //outputs 200!

        const galleryItems = this.props.images.map((image) => {
            return <GalleryItem key={image} image={image} height={this.props.height} />
        });

        return (
            <div>
                <Nav />
                <section>
                    {galleryItems}
                </section>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {

    return {
        images: state.images 
    }
}


function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return bindActionCreators({ fetchImages }, dispatch);
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Gallery);
```

The action:

```
import jsonp from 'jsonp-promise';
import { MF } from '../containers/gallery'


export const FETCH_IMAGES = 'FETCH_IMAGES';

export function fetchImages() {

    const url = `${MF}/home/`
    const request = jsonp(url, {}).promise;

    return {
        type: FETCH_IMAGES,
        payload: request //return promise        
    };
}
```

The reducer:

```
import { FETCH_IMAGES } from '../actions/index'

export default function(state = [], action) {

    switch(action.type) {
        case FETCH_IMAGES:
            var images = action.payload.data.images.images.data.map((image) => {
                return image.image;
            });

            return [ ...images, ...state ];
    }
    return state;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `handleResize` you're updating the state of your `Gallery` component. You then pass the `height` down into `GalleryItem` as a prop.

That means that, inside Gallery, you need to write

```
console.log(this.state.height);
```

While inside GalleryItem you can write:

```
console.log(this.props.height);
```

Comment: This makes sense as mapStateToProps ensures images is available within this.props for the component but this.state.height is unaffected. I get it now.  Thanks!